# Array of random numbers as Object in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am new at java and want to ask you one question. So first what I have to do: My goal is to create different points in one area. I decided to create a class `Koord` for saving the coordinates of the points. I have used an array of 2 elements for this - for the x and y value. After that I added a random generator for x and y (they have to be random).

Here is my class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Koord {

private int number;

private static int numberOfNodes = 0;

public static int[] koord;

public Koord(int x, int y){
    koord = new int[2];
    koord[0] = x;
    koord[1] = y;
    number = ++numberOfNodes;
    }

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public static int getNumberOfNodes() {
    return numberOfNodes;
}

private static int randomFill(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(99);
    return randomNum;
}

public int getX(){
    return koord[0] = randomFill();
       }

public int getY(){
    return koord[1] = randomFill();
    }

}
```

So, until now everything is OK. But now at my main class, I want to create some points and add them to a list. This is also not a problem. The problem starts when I want to print the coordinates of the points. As I am calling the methods `getX()` when I am printing the coordinates of the points in the list, I am getting different coordinates every time.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;


public class Display {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         LinkedList<Koord> ownArea = new LinkedList<Koord>();

      Koord point1 = new Koord(0, 0);
      Koord point2 = new Koord(0, 0);
      Koord point3 = new Koord(0, 0);
      Koord point4 = new Koord(0, 0);
      Koord point5 = new Koord(0, 0);
      Koord point6 = new Koord(0, 0);
      Koord point7 = new Koord(0, 0);


      ownArea.add(point1);
      ownArea.add(point2);
      ownArea.add(point3);
      ownArea.add(point4);
      ownArea.add(point5);
      ownArea.add(point6);
      ownArea.add(point7);



      System.out.println("ListIterator Approach: ");
        ListIterator<Koord> listIterator = ownArea.listIterator();
        while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(listIterator.next().getX());
        }

      System.out.println("ListIterator Approach: ");
        ListIterator<Koord> listIterator2 = ownArea.listIterator();
        while (listIterator2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(listIterator2.next().getX());
        }




 }
}
```

So I know where the problem is, I know that this is wrong, but I don't know how to assign static coordinates to every point and how to print them. And I need this, because I want to operate with the coordinates (comparing them, printing them and so on). I know I have to learn a lot, but for now it will be very helpful, if you can give me some advice.

Comment: Static variables belong to the class. Just make both the variables and accessors not static.

Comment: Why are you boiling up your own class? Just use [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html). No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling `randomFill()` every time you try to `getX()` or `getY()` It will be better to initialize every Koord object with the X and Y value already randomized.

Example:

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
LinkedList<Koord> ownArea = new LinkedList<Koord>();
Koord point1 = new Koord(rand.nextInt(99), rand.nextInt(99));
Koord point2 = new Koord(rand.nextInt(99), rand.nextInt(99));

ownArea.add(point1);
ownArea.add(point2);

for(Koord c : ownArea) {
    System.out.println("x: " + c.getX() + " y: " + c.getY());
}
```

Also in your `Koord` class

The variable `int[] koord` should not be static and change

`getX()` and `getY()` to simply return the value.

In fact this would be a better approach

```
public class Koord {

    private int number;
    private static int numberOfNodes = 0;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Koord(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.number = ++numberOfNodes;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: When doing this, I am getting always the same value for both x and y for all points. Here is my output: ListIterator Approach: 
74
74
74
74
74
74
74
ListIterator Approach: 
74
74
74
74
74
74
74

Comment: @IvoRadev don't make `int[] koord;` be `static`

Comment: Thank you, this not only helped me to complete the task. It also teached me something new (which is more important, because will reuse it in other tasks)

Comment: @IvoRadev you are welcome, now you can accept the answer if you feel it has resolve your question.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the advice. Actually I did it yesterday, but maybe I double clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem

```
public int getX(){
    return koord[0] = randomFill();
}
```

This makes the x random every time you call it!

Move all assignemts to the constructor, and make getX() work like an actual getter, ie. `return x`

I avoid posting code. You should figure it out yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your `getX()` function. I have no idea why you're using `randomFill()` there, since it will continously return a random x value. If you want a random set of coordinates per point, but you only want them to be set once, I suggest calling `randomFill()` in the constructor.

```
public Koord() { // you don't need the x - y parameters if you're calling the random function anyways. 
    koord = new int[2];
    koord[0] = randomFill();
    koord[1] = randomFill();
    number = ++numberOfNodes;
}

// you can now create points like so
Koord point1 = new Koord();
Koord point2 = new Koord();
Koord point3 = new Koord();
```

You'll also need to update your `getX()` (and `getY()`) :

```
public int getX() {
    return koord[0];
}
```